# How to format plain text in php?

Tags: php, html, css, text, formatting

I extracted some text from an **Excel** file and stored it in a **DB**. After that, I fetch this text from the **DB** and display it on a page.

Below is how the problem looks like on the page:

[image]

And this is a screenshot of how it appears in the source code:

[image]

How can I format this paragraph to show in page correctly ?

Comment: I use [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/) and that seems to work fine for me, however you could look for new lines and [replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) them with `<br/>` and same could be done for the other formatting or you couls use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: In HTML, multiple white space characters (newlines, spaces and tabs) are treated as a single space. This is to allow people to indent code/text and not have it affect the layout of the page. If you want to show the text as it should be you need to `pre` format the text through css. You can also use the `nl2br` function in php, but that will only fix the newlines, not the tabs and spaces.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: I get the nl2br is simple, but how i can preformat with css ?

Comment: i got nice format with nl2br http://prntscr.com/9q4gze

Comment: Do not post source as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this

```
<div name="description" ....>
<pre>

.....
here your content
.....

</pre>
</div>
```

if not work let me know

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at HTML Purifier. Pretty good at cleaning up dirty input.
[http://htmlpurifier.org/](http://htmlpurifier.org)